# Why do I catch the "AccessViolationException" exception in av_hwframe_transfer_data () when I run it as a windows service?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, autogen

I write Windows service witch decodig video stream from camera.
I write it on c# with FFMPEG.Autogen wrapper.

My problem is "AccessViolationException" when i run it as service. 
If i run application as Console Application i have no exceptions.

In Stacktrace i see this:

```
в FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg+<>c.<.cctor>b__5_572(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, Int32)
в FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*,Int32)
в VideoProviderService.VideoSources.RTSPVideoSource.TryDecodeNextFrame(Boolean ByRef)
```

Code of TryDecodeNextFrame method:

```
public IntPtr TryDecodeNextFrame(out bool state)
{
    try
    {
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pFrame);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(cpuFrame);
        int error;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
                    error = ffmpeg.av_read_frame(_pFormatContext, pPacket);
                    if (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF)
                    {
                        state = false;
                        return IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    error.ThrowExceptionIfError();
                } while (pPacket->stream_index != _streamIndex);
                ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket).ThrowExceptionIfError();
            }
            finally
            {
                ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
            }
            error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);
        } while (error == ffmpeg.AVERROR(ffmpeg.EAGAIN));
        error.ThrowExceptionIfError();
        ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(cpuFrame, pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
        ptrToFrame = (IntPtr)vfc.Convert(*cpuFrame).data[0];  
    }
    catch
    {
        state = false;
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    state = true;
    return ptrToFrame;
}
```

What i tried to do:

1. I checked arguments of `av_hwframe_transfer_data`.
2. I changed the user for the service.
3. I tried compile as x86 or x64 configuration.

I have no idea how to solve this.
Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not handling properly your frames (pFrame/cpuFrame). Especially, for the cpuFrame you should alloc it in every run and free it at the end of every run. Additionally for the pFrame you should unref it directly after av_hw_frame_transfer_data. Eg:-

```
cpuFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();

....

ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(cpuFrame, pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();

ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pFrame);

.... Process your cpuFrame ...

ffmpeg.av_frame_free(&cpuFrame);

....
```

Comment: I'm not wrote that, but i allocate memory for frames every time when i create context for decoding.  
And i invoke `ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pFrame);` and `ffmpeg.av_frame_free(cpuFrame);` methods at beginning on every step .
The algorithm look like that:
1) Create decoding context
2) Allocate memory for frames
3) Invoke TryDecodeNextFrame method
4) In this method invoke `ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pFrame);` and `ffmpeg.av_frame_free(cpuFrame);`

5) Receive new pFrame. 
6) Copy pFrame to cpuFrame
7) Go back to step 3


I suppose my code does the same steps that you wrote in your answer.

Comment: It's not easy to help, when we cannot see the whole code. But I would bet that you problem is your cpuFrame. Alloc it befeore hwframe_transfer and never unref it (just free it when you are done with it in every process). Try exactly this :-


`code

cpuFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();

fmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(cpuFrame, pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();

ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pFrame);

.... process cpuFrame ...

ffmpeg.av_frame_free(&cpuFrame);


`

dont touch cpuFrame with unref/free elsewhere... just that